# Why is the vector range constructer 10 times faster than the fill constructor?

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, vector, std

I've tested the following two ways of filling a vector with 100'000 elements:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;

int main()
{
    const int n = 100'000;

    cout << "Range constructor: " << endl;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    int nums10[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        nums10[i] = i;
    }
    vector<int> nums11(nums10, nums10 + n);

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "Duration: " << duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << endl;


    cout << "Fill constructor: " << endl;
    t0 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    vector<int> nums1(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        nums1[i] = i;
    }

    t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout << "Duration: " << duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t1 - t0).count() << endl;;
}
```

In my case, the range constructor runs almost 10 times faster (600 microseconds vs ~5000 microseconds).

Why would there be any performance difference here at all? To my understanding there is an equal amount of assignment operations. Using the range constructor, 100'000 elements are assigned to the array, and then all of them are copied to the vector.

Should this not be identical to the fill constructor, in which 100'000 elements are first default initialized to 0, and then all of them are assigned their "real" values in the for loop?

Comment: If you think the range constructor uses a simple loop that's where you're probably mistaken. Look at the assembly output to verify. Tip: Don't bother benchmarking anything but *fully optimized builds*. Debug builds produce utterly meaningless results.

Comment: When dealing in microseconds, the performance doesn't matter

Comment: @tadman: And of course, the corollary to "only benchmark fully optimized builds" is "toy problems are often too simple, so make sure the compiler isn't optimizing all the work away completely". If you don't *use* the results, or the results are used in a way that is predictable at compile time, one or both might do no work at all at runtime, even if real world code that did similar things had to do the work (due to lack of predictability). I suspect you're using a debug build which doesn't inline `vector`'s `operator[]`, making artificial differences, but you haven't provided build settings.

Comment: @ShadowRanger This is true, sometimes you end up benchmarking two different empty functions and are actually measuring how fast your CPU can turbo up and/or thermally throttle.

Comment: @tadman I'm not familiar with assembly unfortunately. Could you explain what is actually happening, if it is not iterating and copying the values in the range constructor? Optimization has been disabled for this example. I understand the difference is meaningless in absolute terms, but I'm curious why there is a difference here at all.

Comment: In your Fill Constructor test case, invoke `nums1.reserve(n)` before entering the for-loop.  I suspect the performance will be near identical as a result of the vector not having to resize periodically for each added element.

Comment: @selbie surprisingly, `reserve` + `push_back` [isn't better with clang](https://quick-bench.com/q/Gx7c0EkctWS5aKfG1MTukouK0wM).

Comment: It's not clear what is or isn't happening without really digging into it, but keep in mind that a modern CPU is far from a simple thing, and optimizing compilers are extremely complex. Unless this is a **measurable performance problem**, ignore it and just put in the simplest version that achieves your goal. Deal with it later if it proves to be a problem.

Comment: I've edited the question with my full source code. @selbie Why would my vector have to resize periodically? If I understand correctly, because I am specifying the array size in the call to the constructor, the entire memory is reserved at initialization and initialized to the default value 0.

Comment: @selbie `reserve(n)` won't do anything at all, since the vector was already initialized with size `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's the compiled code on godbolt, with `gcc -O0`](https://godbolt.org/z/TzEv9491n).

In the first test:

- the loop to fill the array (lines 49-57 of the assembly) is compiled as a simple loop, with a store to memory on each iteration.  It's not well optimized (the index variable is kept on the stack instead of in a register, and redundantly moved back and forth) but at least it's inline code and doesn't make any function calls.
- the range constructor is a single call to the precompiled constructor in the library (line 69).  We can assume the library function was compiled with aggressive optimizations; it probably calls a highly optimized `memcpy` in handwritten assembly.  So it's probably about as fast as it could be.

In the second test:

- The fill constructor is a library call (line 113).  Again this is presumably about as fast as it can be (probably calling a hand-optimized `memset`).
- Your loop to fill the vector (lines 118-130) generates a function call to `std::vector<int>::operator[]` on **every iteration** (line 126).  Even though `operator[]` itself is probably pretty fast, having been precompiled, the overhead of a function call every time, including the code to reload registers with its arguments, is a killer.  If you were compiling with optimizations, this call could be inlined; all that overhead would go away and you'd again just have a single store to memory per iteration.  But you're not optimizing, so guess what?  Performance is deeply sub-optimal.

[With optimizations](https://godbolt.org/z/M79hjcEPY) the second test is apparently faster.  This makes sense as it only has to write the same block of memory twice, never reading; whereas the first one involves writing a block of memory, then reading it back to write the second block.

Moral: unoptimized code can be really bad, and two pieces of code that *could* be optimized into something very similar may turn out very different if such optimizations are not attempted.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I didn't realize that function calls from the [] operator matter in this context.